# Design pattern for event grouping

Tags: python, events, model, message

I would to implement a existing model with an event-driven (or message-driven) architecture.
Some entities need to fire events to update other entities.

For entities of class B depends on entities of class A.
So when an A entity is changing, I will fire an event to let some B entities to update
(several A entities are "linked" to one B entity).

In some case, I need to update all A entities. This will generate events.
**But most of those events will be "redondant"** because I will update each B entity
several times. **I would like to "group" or "delay" those events**.

What are the **usefull design patterns** for my use case ?
Do I need grouping pending events ?
Do I need delaying events ?
Do I need event invalidation ? based on time-stamp ?

I am using Python but examples in any langages will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it just invites complexity. If it's not a performance problem, I'd keep it simple and let the redundant events fold themselves. This way the code is kept simple and your don't have to make decisions which events to coalesce and which should be separate (which may change as your model evolves).

Comment: Are you using an existing event/signal-framework, or do you implement a homebrew mechanism?

Comment: @alex-b : This is a performance problem ! I would like to turn my model into an event-driven one to trigger only the necessary computation parts. The goal is to make the computation time as short as possible by only recomputing the involved parts.

Comment: @don-question : I think about using a pub/sub engine like Redis and a async stack like twisted. But it sounds a bit heavy so I am investigating for a _smarter_ solution.

Comment: redis is afaik not an observer-pattern framework. It may use it, but it's essentially a NoSql-DB. Could you provide some example-/pseudo code of what you have in mind? as it is, your question is way to broad

Comment: @don-question : I use the [pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) feature of Redis. I will update the question with pseudo code.